# Is rdflib's ConjunctiveGraph with IOMemory store thread-safe?

Tags: rdflib

I am pulling multiple datasets from multiple sources and want to parallelize that using the `threading` library in Python 3.8.2.
All datasets end in different contexts in a `ConjunctiveGraph`, which uses an `IOMemory` store.
I saw that a `ConcurrentStore` exists, but there is no example, not documented that much and does not implement the `Store` interface, which makes it unusable.

While reading through the code of `IOMemory`, I saw places where the existence of elements in collections is checked and then things get added without that I saw locking code around.

So is `IOMemory` already thread-safe or do I need to 'fix' `ConcurrentStore`?

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer perhaps dependent on whether the underlying Python objects are themselves threadsafe? Python `set()` underlies the RDFlib `Graph`.

You could also perhaps create independent `Graph`s and then merge them all into a `ConjunctiveGraph` or a `Dataset` once they have each been fully populated. That may bypass the issue.

Any work on `ConcurrentStore` would be appreciated though!